# EJB CDI interceptors on chained calls

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, interceptor

I have Java EE software, which has many EJBs separated by specific functionalities. I'd like to reuse a maximum amount of code.

In this scenario, I have a problem with the database transactions. Take in mind: I have an EJB which has to add products and tax information in a database. This process involves two entities, and this operation needs to be atomic for the database.

For this behavior I annotated the method `addProducsAndTaxes` with an annotation called `@myAmonicTransaction` which I have created.

Now I have several EJBs that call the EJB function above, and need to join this atomic transaction with the database. It uses the same annotation `AmonicTransaction`, but now an interceptor is called two times; once for the most external EJB and once more for an internal EJB.

I'd like to know if there's a way to know if the most internal interceptor is in context of the external EJB in order to avoid this double intercept.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you're duplicating the transaction behavior of EJB already.  Is there a reason why you can't use JTA 1.2's transaction interceptor and start a new transaction only within the method `addProducsAndTaxes`